# stream live video to Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, android-video-player

How can I stream live video to Android (2.1 and higher), I have two links: `m3u8` and `f4m` (As I know, f4m  is not supported).

From what I saw on stackoverflow, there is a way to stream m3u8 with vitamio (but the link is not working ).

Is there any other way to stream m3u8 video ? 
Maybe there is other format that I can use ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because no one answered my question, I will do it myself.

If you want to perform HLT (HTTP Live Stream) on Android 2.1 and higher you may use the vitamio library.

Site at: (http://www.vitamio.org/).

Here is code example:
The main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:paddingLeft="2px" android:paddingRight="2px"
            android:paddingTop="2px" android:paddingBottom="2px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

            <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/VideoView">               
            </io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView>
</LinearLayout>
```

the Class:

```
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.MediaController;
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class LiveStrimingTestActivity extends Activity{

    VideoView videoView;

    private void test_2(){
        String httpLiveUrl = "http://aj.lsops.net/live/aljazeer_en_high.sdp/playlist.m3u8";   
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        test_2();             
    }     
}
```

Comment: Please check below before you add this library in your project on api level 23.
https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues/394#issuecomment-231802573

Answer (score 4):

I have tested the same stream on devices with OS 2.2, 2.3.4 and 4.0.4. This stream plays very well with regular VideoView on the devices I have got. I dont use MediaController with live streams. The rest of the code is simple.

```
initializeVideoView();
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://aj.lsops.net/live/aljazeer_en_high.sdp/playlist.m3u8"));
mVideoView.setMediaController(null);
mVideoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

[KickFlip](https://kickflip.io) is an open source and free library for Video Streaming and it is super easy t setup.

```
Kickflip.initWithApiKey(API_KEY, API_SECRET);
Kickflip.startBroadcastActivity(this, mBroadcastListener);
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

To add vitamio to your project just add this dependency.
compile 'me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2'
and then as @butter told you to do.
Happy Coding.good luck