# How to Stream and play HLS (or) .m3u8 format Video

Tags: android, vitamio

I'm able to play HLS Live Video Streaming  on my Android Device. I am able to play the Video if the Device is Installed with the **Vitamio Plugin**.

Could anyone tell me how to Embed the **Vitamio Plugin** into our Android App  without intstalling it externally?

Is there any way to Stream HLS Videos?

Note: I refer to this link [stream live video to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898643/stream-live-video-to-android)